# Moovweb Login - Failed to generate key

Tags: key, moovweb

Working on a Mac, trying to work through the Quickstart. Downloaded and installed SDK. I am now blocked trying to login to MoovCloud due to the absence of a public key. Got an error trying to generate one. Can anyone point me to a possible solution?

```
$ moov login
Please enter your MoovCloud credentials:
Email: someone@example.com
Password (typing will be hidden): 

Could not find an existing public key.
Would you like to generate one? [Yn] 
Generating new key pair...
Error: Failed to generate key: signal 5
$ _
```

Comment: Generated a key manually and all is now well. See https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys for details.

Comment: Hmm my understanding is that this should have worked for you. You should file a ticket with help.moovweb.com.